# Which is the best method to develop a Desktop/Mobile application

Tags: jquery, web-applications, mobile, jquery-mobile

Just like Responsive web design does the trick for both **mobile** and **desktop**, I want to know about some framework where applications developed when viewed in a desktop it displays like a normal web app and when it comes to a smartphone or tablet it should render like `jQuery` mobile layout.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check the UserAgent in your server code and render the appropriate "Desktop" or "Mobile" theme/ui for your app. There aren't any frameworks that do this for you automatically.

Comment: Thanks Chris.. KendoUI is something which is close enough, but the problem comes when displaying data grids and charts. I am not just looking at applying theme (even if that not possible its ok with me), but my primary concern is how to make a web app completely adapt to a smartphone..